# Funnel visualisation goal in custom report

Tags: google-analytics

I have Funnel Visualisation set up with three steps and 1st one marked as **required**.

Then there's Custom Report with Landing Page dimension and some metrics:

- Page Views as first metric
- Funnel Goal Completions as second metric
- Funnel Goal Conversion Rate as third metric

While there's no conversions in Funnel Visualisation yet there are conversions in Custom Report.

I was reading documentation and probably have some explanation - just want to confirm my idea of what is going on:

**Q1**
Funnel is being filtered by 1st required step and there was no conversion which included visit to required page first?

**Q2**
In Custom report meaning of the conversion is just user who entered in particular Landing Page and then visited the last step from the Funnel Goal (omitting any required steps as Funnel conditions apply only in Funnel)?

**Q3**
If there's required step in Funnel backfill never happens?

**Q4**
If the same user is able to go thorough the Funnel steps multiple times how many conversions it will score? I've read that only one per session but how can I know how much time it takes before user will be counted as new session? Even if it will be counted as new session it will probably have the same User ID and will be counted as returning user - will it score another conversion in Funnel Visualisation?